# How to give hint in Java that two type parameters are actually the same type?

Tags: java, android

I'm working with AOSP's [`CaptureRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest) and its associated [`CaptureRequest.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.Builder) classes, and have (albeit very *unusual* case of) a need to copy settings key-values from an existing instance of `CaptureRequest` to a new instance of `CaptureRequest.Builder`<sup>1</sup>.

The basic code here that I want to run is the following:

```java
        for(CaptureRequest.Key<?> key : request.getKeys()) {
            builder.set(key, request.get(key));
        }
```

... where `CaptureRequest.Builder.set()` function is defined as `<T> void set(Key<T> key, T value)`, and `CaptureRequest.get()` is defined as `<T> T get(Key<T> key)`.
But that makes compiler barf with the following error:

```java
Source.java:2: error: method set in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
                builder.set(key, request.get(key));
                       ^
  required: Key<T>,T
  found: Key<CAP#1>,CAP#2
  reason: inferred type does not conform to lower bound(s)
    inferred: CAP#1
    lower bound(s): Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>set(Key<T>,T)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
```

If I'm interpreting the error correctly, it's trying to say that it cannot relate `<T>`s of two functions as being the same one `T`.  So to give it a hint that it's the same `T`, I created some helper functions that should make it obvious that it's the same `T`, and so I have this:

```java
private static <T> T getKeyValue(CaptureRequest request, CaptureRequest.Key<T> key) {
    return (T)request.<T>get(key);
}

private static <T> void setKeyValue(CaptureRequest.Builder builder, CaptureRequest.Key<T> key) {
    builder.<T>set(key, (T)MyClass.<T>getKeyValue(key));
}

.....

        for(CaptureRequest.Key<?> key : request.getKeys()) {
            setKeyValue(builder, key);
        }
```

This fails to pacify the Java compiler and it spits out very similar error to the previous one:

```java
  Source.java:6: error: method getKeyValue in class MyClass cannot be applied to given types;
        builder.<T>set(key, (T)MyClass.<T>getKeyValue(key));
                                      ^
  required: CaptureRequest,Key<T#1>
  found: Key<T#2>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>getKeyValue(CaptureRequest,Key<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>setKeyValue(Builder,Key<T#2>)
```

How can I perform this [what should be simple] copy of key-values in a sane way?

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I know that's weird and a bit backwards from typical use of API, hence "unusual".  Context is that already built request (beyond library's scope) is percolating through a library that needs to shadow request with its own, mostly mimicking the original, but slightly amended, and said library doesn't have access to original builder to build the shadow sibling request. Yes, it's weird and is beyond the scope of this question. This question is really about Java's template methods and apparent compilation error.

Comment: It looks like the implementation of `setKeyValue` should just be `builder.set(key, request.get(key))`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, the point of `setKeyValue` using `T` everywhere explicitly was an attempt to pacify compiler by telling it directly relationship of types, rather than letting it use type-deduction that seemed like it was not succeeding.  That's why `T` was seeded everywhere possible (but didn't help).  But Shadov's answer below did the trick without need for `setKeyValue` or even `getKeyValue` functions.

Comment: You _can_ make this work without any casting, unsafe or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

`builder.set((CaptureRequest.Key<Object>)key, request.get(key));`

Pretty sure it should work.